# Subsetting a dataframe in pandas according to column name values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that i need to split up. It is much larger than this, but here is an example:

```
ID A  B

a   0  0

b   1  1 

c   2  2
```

and I have a list: `keep_list = ['ID','A']`
and another list: `recode_list = ['ID','B']`

I'd like the split the dataframe up by the column headers into two dataframes: one dataframe with those columns and values whose column headers match the keep_list, and one with those column headers and data that match the recode_alleles list. Every code I have tried thus far has not worked as it is trying to compare the values to the list, not the column names.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame's name is `df`:

you can simply do 
`df[keep_list]` and `df[recode_list]` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [`index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(keep_list)]
df2 = df[df.columns.intersection(recode_list)]
```